# How to fix fatal error: module 'React' in AST file

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Any tips how to fix this? I have tried clean the build folder in Xcode and also manually deleted DerivedData folder, but it does not fix this.

This is what I know so far: It does not crash when developing locally with physical iOS phone or in simulator. TestFlight builds just seems to randomly crash when App is clicked to launch it.

fatal error: module 'React' in AST file '/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/T2AP1DY9NK4/React-3I70GVOCLJ3SS.pcm' (imported by AST file '/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobilePlayer-edutlwanzjvdknakzztrwppfpjhb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/mobilePlayer-Bridging-Header-swift_1WSAJVE6367HH-clang_T2AP1DY9NK4.pch') is not defined in any loaded module map file; maybe you need to load '/Users/USERNAME/mobilePlayer/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core/React/React-Core.modulemap'?

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE:
I can remove this problem, disabling precompiled bridging header option

Go to target > Build Settings > Swift Compiler - General > set `Precompiled Bridging Header` to `No`

this work for my project that was ejected (prebuild) from Expo 46

Expo Env Info:

```
  expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 12.6
      Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 16.17.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 8.15.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 2022.10.10.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    Managers:
      CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 16.0, macOS 12.3, tvOS 16.0, watchOS 9.0
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 31, 33
        Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 29.0.3, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 33.0.0
        System Images: android-31 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9014738
      Xcode: 14.0.1/14A400 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      babel-preset-expo: ~9.2.0 => 9.2.0 
      expo: ~46.0.13 => 46.0.15 
      react: 18.0.0 => 18.0.0 
      react-dom: 18.0.0 => 18.0.0 
      react-native: 0.69.6 => 0.69.6 
      react-native-web: ~0.18.7 => 0.18.9 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      eas-cli: 2.3.0
      expo-cli: 6.0.6
    Expo Workflow: bare
```

Comment: Also ran into this issue, also ejected from Expo (49).